# Trying to find the name of this anime

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find this anime's name in this video at the 9:25 mark, anyone have any idea?

Comment: One of the _Ghost in the Shell_ series, I believe. The guy on the left is a dead giveaway.

Comment: Will happily up-vote when the question's *title* becomes informative. :) Welcome to SFF.SE SomeGal!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Gallifreyan is *almost* correct. It's from [Ghost in the Shell 2: Innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_2:_Innocence).

The modelling of Batou shown in the clip is older and has a gaunter face than the Batou of Stand Alone Complex. Moreover, Togusa (the guy on the right) has darker hair and less rounded eyes than his SAC counterpart.  This is the drawing style of the movie Ghost In the Shell 2: Innocence.

[image: B&T]
It's a sequel to [the original Ghost in the Shell movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_(1995_film)), which was widely acclaimed for being a game changer in anime.

That said, I highly recommend watching GITS:SAC if you want a longer experience than the movie medium can provide. It's a great show, and both the show and the movies deal with great topics.

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out, can't wait. Thanks!

Comment: Damn it, man - I was going to add this to the list of successful answers about works I've never seen/read.

Comment: @SomeGal Be sure to click the check sign by my answer!

Comment: More precisely, the particular scene OP is asking about takes place around the 57 minute mark.

Answer (score 4):

My bet is [*Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Stand_Alone_Complex). It's a TV series within the *Ghost in the Shell* universe, which originated with [Masamune Shirow's manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_(manga)).

The guy with the glasses on the left is called [Batou](http://ghostintheshell.wikia.com/wiki/Batou), and is instantly recognisable.

[image]

Sadly, I don't know which season or episode this is. If you're willing to get into the *GitS* universe, you may find [this Q&A on Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2922/28456) or [Suggested starting place for Ghost in the Shell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20628/70236) on this site helpful.